# How to inject file.log to logstash and display it via kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, ec2-ami, elk

I using docker container and docker-compose, to create ELK containers, after the containers created i should inject file into logstash and display it via docker

I'm havent work on docker until three days ago, i working at this problem, surfed at least 10 websites+youtube and cant understand what should i do. 
I sucssesed in creatind docker container, install/create (not sure how to say it) docker-compose. 
I have pulled the docker-elk/ from git, so i have ready yml files for docker-compose, logstash, kibana and elastic search, i have tried to push file into logstash but i cant get if i did it right, and how to check it at all

i saw an option to check ip addresses of running containers and run it via ip:5061, ip:9200 but nothing have worked

## i have installed docker and pulled docker elk

sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker

## Download docker-elk:

git clone https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk
sudo curl -L

## downloaded docker compose

https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose

## and created elk containers- i have tried two commands, the second one worked #better

sudo docker-compose -d
sudo docker-compose -f /full addres/ docker-compose.yml up

I expect to show injected into logstash log file via kibana graph

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a log shipper like [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) and that do not comes with the ELK stack. after you configure your file beate to send logs to logstash you can see the logs